# Deleting a Pattern from a String

Tags: regex, string, algorithm, dynamic-programming

I am not sure how to go about coding this. So, I have a string called S and a pattern string called M. I want to delete all occurrences of M in S. But, when I delete one occurrence of M in S, I could possibly create another. For example, given the word "aajjk" and the pattern "aj". After the first deletion, it would become "ajk". In this new string, another occurrence of "aj" has come after the first deletion. The final string after all deletions would then be "k". Could you give me some tips on how to approach this problem, some psuedocode would be helpful as I need practice in implementation.

Comment: Please don't vandalize your own questions; that makes the answers which people spend time writing considerably less useful.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a worst-case linear-time algorithm, then one approach is to construct a finite automaton that accepts strings ending in M (e.g., Knuth--Morris--Pratt), and then run this pseudocode.

```
initialize a state stack to [initial state of the automaton]
initialize an empty character stack
for each character c in S:
    let q be the top of the state stack
    push delta(q, c) onto the state stack,
      where delta is the transition function of the automaton
    push c onto the character stack
    if the top of the state stack is an accepting state:
        pop length(M) values from both stacks
output the contents of the character stack
```

Comment: Hi, I have some clarifications. What is the transition function and what is the automaton?

Comment: @PrashSom There's a whole literature on string matching algorithms, with which I assumed some familiarity.

Answer (score 0):

In JS you could do something like this:

```
function delPattern(patt, str) {
    var res = str.replace(patt, "");
    if(patt.test(res) == true) {
        delPattern(patt, res);
    } else {
        console.log(res);
    }

}

var str = "aajjk"; 
delPattern(/aj/g, str);
```

**"patt"** is the Pattern. Here "**/aj/g**". "g" stands for global, that every pattern is matched. With the function "**replace**" you replace your pattern with "". After that, you ask if the pattern does exist one more time "i**f(patt.test(res) == true)**". If it is true, so do the same thing again. Else, give me the result.

Answer (score 0):

Simplistically, loop as long as performing a replacement results in a different string.  Pseudocode:

```
lastS = null
while(lastS != S)
    lastS = S
    S.replace(M, '')
```